# Why is my if else statement returning only returning second statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am fairly new to coding and I'm currently doing the Odin Project. One of the projects from there asks to build a rock, paper, scissors game. I'm not trying to do anything fancy, so I'm just having the result show in the console. Every time I run the code and input any response all that returns is "it's a draw" every time. Here is the code:

```js
let playerChoice = prompt("Enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors:").toLowerCase();

let computerRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);

function computerRand() {
  if (computerRandom === 1) {
    return "paper";
  } else if (computerRandom === 2) {
    return "rock";
  } else if (computerRandom === 3) {
    return "scissors";
  }
};

computerRand();

function playRound(playerSel, computerPlay) {
  let playerChoice = playerSel;
  let computerRand = computerPlay;
  if ((playerSel === 'rock' && computerPlay === 'scissors') || (playerSel === 'scissors' && computerPlay === 'paper') || (playerSel === 'paper' && computerPlay === 'rock')) {
    return "Player Wins";
  } else if (computerPlay == playerSel) {
    return "it's a draw";
  } else if ((computerPlay === 'rock' && playerSel === 'scissors' || computerPlay === 'scissors' && playerSel === 'paper' || computerPlay === 'paper' && playerSel === 'rock')) {
    return "You lose";
  } else {
    return "That is not an option"
  }
};
playRound();
console.log(playRound());
```

Comment: Because you do not pass anything into your function! `playRound();` and `playRound(playerSel, computerPlay)`

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you tried adding breakpoints to inspect variables during run-time? Have you tried outputting values to the console in your `playRound` function?

Comment: You call `computerRand();` and do nothing with what the function returns.

Comment: You need to learn how function calling and returning works. SO is not a replacement for learning the basics of computer programming.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you do not pass anything as a parameter when calling the `playRound()` function, so the parameter is always the same (`undefined`).

For example, the following function call does not return a tie `console.log(playRound("paper","rock"));`

Comment: A parameter that isn't passed is `undefined`, not `null`.